# Unable to add a border-bottom in ion-item

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I want the border of ion-item to touch till the ends.When I write the **css** class for it, the browser does not apply the styles.

[image]
**.html**

```
<ion-item class="item-class">
<input type="text" placeholder="Username">
<ion-icon item-end name="people"></ion-icon>
</ion-item>
```

**.css**

```
.item-class {

border-bottom: 1px solid #F1F1F1;

}
```

You can see the screen-shot below

[image]

After adding !important to the border-bottom property in css the result are visible as follows:

[image]

When clicking in the input field the bule line is also visible.

[image]

Comment: What happens if you add `!important` after your property value? https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-zmldbe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In side your variable.scss file add this in the android section.

```
$text-input-md-highlight-color-invalid: transparent;
$text-input-md-highlight-color-valid: transparent;
$text-input-md-show-invalid-highlight: transparent;
$text-input-md-highlight-color: transparent;
$text-input-md-show-valid-highlight: transparent;
```

Inorder to avoid the item line use this

`<ion-item class="item-class" no-line>`
(or)

inside your respected scss file

```
.item-inner {
    padding-right: 8px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #F1F1F1;
}
```

Comment: cool that's done for highlighting one. Can you solve for item's default border overlapping by boredem-bottom property created?

Comment: check once again with my updated answer it will apply the color `#F1F1F1`

Comment: yes please explain me i am not getting your question ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166448/discussion-between-aditya-and-mohan-gopi).